# Undefined constants with Twitter API?

Tags: php, twitter

I'm trying to create a Twitter Widget for my Wordpress site, this widget get a last five tweets from my account on Twitter using Twitter API 1.1.

I'm using this code:

```
<?php # Load Twitter class
require_once ('twitteroauth.php');

# Define constants
define('TWEET_LIMIT', 5);
define('TWITTER_USERNAME', 'myusername');
define('CONSUMERKEY', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('CONSUMERSECRET', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('ACCESSTOKEN', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('ACCESSTOKENSECRET', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

# Create the connection
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

# Migrate over to SSL/TLS
$twitter->ssl_verifypeer = true;

# Load the Tweets
$tweets = $twitter->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => TWITTER_USERNAME, 'exclude_replies' => 'true', 'include_rts' => 'false', 'count' => TWEET_LIMIT));

# Example output
if(!empty($tweets)) {
    foreach($tweets as $tweet) {

        # Access as an object
        $tweetText = $tweet['text'];

        # Make links active
        $tweetText = preg_replace("/(http://|(www.\))(([^\s<]{4,68})[^\s<]*)/", '<a href="http://$2$3" target="_blank">$1$2$4</a>', $tweetText);

        # Linkify user mentions
        $tweetText = preg_replace("/@(w+)/", '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>', $tweetText);

        # Linkify tags
        $tweetText = preg_replace("/#(w+)/", '<a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=$1" target="_blank">#$1</a>', $tweetText);

        # Output
        echo $tweetText;

    }
}

# Put this after fetching Tweets
$twitter = '';

# Create the HTML output
if(!empty($tweets)) {
    foreach($tweets as $tweet) {
        $twitter .= '<article>
            <aside class="avatar">
                <a href="http://twitter.com/'.$tweet['from_user'].'" target="_blank">
                    <img alt="'.$tweet['from_user'].'" src="'.$tweet['user']['profile_image_url'].'" />
                </a>
            </aside>
            <p>'.$tweet['created_at'].'</p>
            <p>'.$tweet['text'].'</p>
        </article>';
    }
} ?>
```

But, PHP returns nothing :(

When i see the log file (/var/apache2/logs) have these lines:

```
[Wed Apr 16 11:41:17.335808 2014] [:error] [pid 1983] [client 127.0.0.1:XXXX] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CONSUMER_KEY - assumed 'CONSUMER_KEY' in /home/user/websites/html/dev_twitterwidget/index.php on line 14
[Wed Apr 16 11:41:17.335870 2014] [:error] [pid 1983] [client 127.0.0.1:XXXX] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CONSUMER_SECRET - assumed 'CONSUMER_SECRET' in /home/user/websites/html/dev_twitterwidget/index.php on line 14
[Wed Apr 16 11:41:17.335878 2014] [:error] [pid 1983] [client 127.0.0.1:XXXX] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant ACCESS_TOKEN - assumed 'ACCESS_TOKEN' in /home/user/websites/html/dev_twitterwidget/index.php on line 14
[Wed Apr 16 11:41:17.335885 2014] [:error] [pid 1983] [client 127.0.0.1:XXXX] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET - assumed 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET' in /home/user/websites/html/dev_twitterwidget/index.php on line 14
[Wed Apr 16 11:41:18.637099 2014] [:error] [pid 1983] [client 127.0.0.1:XXXX] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: text in /home/user/websites/html/dev_twitterwidget/index.php on line 27
[Wed Apr 16 11:41:18.642361 2014] [:error] [pid 1983] [client 127.0.0.1:XXXX] PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '/' in /home/user/websites/html/dev_twitterwidget/index.php on line 30
[Wed Apr 16 11:41:18.642834 2014] [:error] [pid 1983] [client 127.0.0.1:XXXX] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: from_user in /home/user/websites/html/dev_twitterwidget/index.php on line 52
[Wed Apr 16 11:41:18.642905 2014] [:error] [pid 1983] [client 127.0.0.1:XXXX] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: from_user in /home/user/websites/html/dev_twitterwidget/index.php on line 53
[Wed Apr 16 11:41:18.642913 2014] [:error] [pid 1983] [client 127.0.0.1:XXXX] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: user in /home/user/websites/html/dev_twitterwidget/index.php on line 53
[Wed Apr 16 11:41:18.642919 2014] [:error] [pid 1983] [client 127.0.0.1:XXXX] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: created_at in /home/user/websites/html/dev_twitterwidget/index.php on line 56
[Wed Apr 16 11:41:18.642925 2014] [:error] [pid 1983] [client 127.0.0.1:XXXX] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: text in /home/user/websites/html/dev_twitterwidget/index.php on line 57
[Wed Apr 16 11:45:40.954884 2014] [:error] [pid 1985] [client 127.0.0.1:XXXX] PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '/' in /home/user/websites/html/dev_twitterwidget/index.php on line 33
```

Ubuntu 13.10 x64
PHP 5.5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined as

```
CONSUMERKEY
```

and using as

```
new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY
```

Not just the above all of them defined as some constant and using something else

Hence the issue.

```
define('TWITTER_USERNAME', 'myusername');
define('CONSUMERKEY', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('CONSUMERSECRET', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('ACCESSTOKEN', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('ACCESSTOKENSECRET', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
```

The below should be the correct one.

```
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMERKEY, CONSUMERSECRET, ACCESSTOKEN, ACCESSTOKENSECRET);
```

Also check for other mismatch in the code.

Comment: Okay, apparently passed, but now see this error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: See here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113906/fatal-error-with-twitter-api-cannot-use-object-of-type-stdclass-as-array